# How to change background color on disabled textbox

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change background color of disabled text-box, but mobile version looks a bit odd, any idea what property is doing that color?
See first image, I would like to have result on mobile version as is showing on second image.

this is how it looks like on mobile version:
[image]

And here is how it looks like on desctop version:
[image]
code:

```
input[disabled] { 
    color: #439d8e; 
    font-family: Roboto;
    background: white;
}
```

Comment: This is weird. Can you provide a fiddle/codepen that reproduce the problem? What mobile browser are you using?

Comment: I'd also try `opacity: 1`, maybe it's a browser rule. Also try a sanitizer.

Comment: @CristianTraìna I did try opacity:1 didn'help... What is sanitizer?

Comment: opacity: 1 !important

Comment: @CristianTraìna Now the opacity works, but now is a same effect on color of the text

Comment: @NagaSaiA hi, i did use opacity:1 before but now it works just fine, but the effect same as before has a color of text, witch is another problem

Comment: -webkit-text-fill-color: white;
  background:white;

Comment: try using bakground white , text fill color along with opacity -- https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/OvaZXZ

Comment: Try and post you complete code segment

Answer (score 1):

Something like this worked for me in the past:

```
.item {
    -webkit-text-fill-color: white; 
    -webkit-opacity: 1; 
    background: white;
}
```